# R cannot read *.shp shapefile with rgdal

Tags: shapefile, r, rgdal

I'm trying to open `ne_10m_urban_areas.shp` with `rgdal::readOGR`, but it gives me the bellow error

```r
library(rgdal)
a <- readOGR(dsn = path.expand("C:/.../Desktop/"),
layer = "ne_10m_urban_areas.shp")
```

> `>` Error in ogrInfo(dsn = dsn, layer = layer, encoding = encoding, use_iconv = use_iconv,  :
>
> `>` Cannot open layer

```
a <- shapefile("C:/.../Desktop/ne_10m_urban_areas.shp")
```

> `>` Error: file.exists(extension(x, ".shx")) is not TRUE

```
file.exists("C:/.../Desktop/ne_10m_urban_areas.shp")
```

> `>` [1] TRUE

Comment: All you need is the name of the shapefile so, remove ".shp" from the name of dataset.

Answer (score 4):

This bit:

```
a <- shapefile("C:/.../Desktop/ne_10m_urban_areas.shp")
 Error: file.exists(extension(x, ".shx")) is not TRUE
```

tells us that there is no `ne_10m_urban_areas.shx` file - note the file extension `SHX` not `SHP`. A valid shapefile needs a `.shp`, a `.shx` and usually a `.dbf` file (as well as possible others). Do you have all those in the same folder? I don't think so. There's your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible you don't have even read permissions over the folder you are trying to open a layer from. This problem is especially pesky if running stuff from a docker container. In order to give yourself permission just type:

`chmod -R 777 /path/to/folder`

in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your file names match exactly. I had the same issue and I had all the files in the same folder, but the names didn't match exactly. Once they matched then it worked.