# ".shp" extension missing in R while other layers are present

Tags: shapefile, r, rgdal

I am trying to read a shapefile in R using the command:

```
rivnet <- readOGR(dsn = 'sa_riv_30s',layer = 'sa_riv_30s')
```

However, the '.shp' layer does not seem to be recognized by R. The layers present in the file directory include: shp.htm, shp.xml, .sbx, and .prj. I've tried restarting my computer, updating rgdal, using file.exist() to check and receive false. I can see it in the file directory on my computer, and I have read it in the past.

It is not just this shapefile that is not showing up. I have several shapefiles in my directory and can't read any of them in R.

Comment: Try using full path in `dsn` argument and `driver = 'ESRI Shapefile'`

Comment: Have you tried the shapefile() function out of the raster package? Try something like: myshapefile <- shapefile(file.choose()) Once you hit -enter- a window should pop up allowing you to select the .shp file.

Comment: Hi @NewAtGis, thanks for the suggestions. The problem is that R does not seem to recognize that these file exists. When using the shapefile function I get: Error in .local(x, ...) : file.exists(extension(x, ".shp")) is not TRUE. The same thing seems to be happening with opening gdb. I've checked the file paths and tried using the full extension, but I'm not sure why R is not recognizing the files..

Comment: I also have tried checking the permission on this folder, based on this post (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/283095/r-cannot-read-shp-shapefile-with-rgdal), but it does seem like this is a system issue

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work after trying two things. I am not sure what was the cause, but the two things were:

1. Checking permissions: [R cannot read *.shp shapefile with rgdal](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/283095/r-cannot-read-shp-shapefile-with-rgdal)
2. I zipped the folder of interest. For some reason, I didn't even have to work with the zipped folder. The shapefile suddenly appeared in the uncompressed folder.